# Why can't download with transmission the second time?

Tags: bittorrent, transmission

Download the torrent and start transimission-cli:

```
transmission-cli  Downloads/debian-11.5.0-arm64-DVD-1.iso.torrent  -w  /tmp
```

It works, the `debian-11.5.0-arm64-DVD-1.iso` can be downloaded to `/tmp`. Then i remove it:

```
rm -f  /tmp/debian-11.5.0-arm64-DVD-1.iso.
```

And start the download again:

```
transmission-cli  /home/debian/debian-11.5.0-arm64-DVD-1.iso.torrent  -w  /tmp  
transmission-cli 3.00 (bb6b5a062e)
[2023-07-15 14:59:32.825] Transmission 3.00 (bb6b5a062e) started
[2023-07-15 14:59:32.826] RPC Server: Adding address to whitelist: 127.0.0.1
[2023-07-15 14:59:32.826] RPC Server: Adding address to whitelist: ::1
[2023-07-15 14:59:32.826] DHT: Reusing old id
[2023-07-15 14:59:32.826] DHT: Bootstrapping from 97 IPv4 nodes
[2023-07-15 14:59:32.876] debian-11.5.0-arm64-DVD-1.iso: No data found! Ensure your drives are connected or use "Set Location". To re-download, remove the torrent and re-add it.
[2023-07-15 14:59:32.877] Saved "/home/debian/.config/transmission/torrents/232af54148c2d99d48b8da54376ab888f14a745c.torrent"
[2023-07-15 14:59:32.877] debian-11.5.0-arm64-DVD-1.iso: No data found! Ensure your drives are connected or use "Set Location". To re-download, remove the torrent and re-add it.
[2023-07-15 14:59:32.877] debian-11.5.0-arm64-DVD-1.iso: No data found! Ensure your drives are connected or use "Set Location". To re-download, remove the torrent and re-add it.
[2023-07-15 14:59:33.078] Saved "/home/debian/.config/transmission/settings.json"

[2023-07-15 14:59:33.078] DHT: Not saving nodes, DHT not ready
[2023-07-15 14:59:33.078] Port Forwarding: Stopped
[2023-07-15 14:59:33.078] debian-11.5.0-arm64-DVD-1.iso: Removing torrent
[2023-07-15 14:59:33.078] debian-11.5.0-arm64-DVD-1.iso: Pausing
```

Why can't re-download with transmission-cli?